# PySimpleGUI drawimage not displaying image

Tags: image, display, pysimplegui

I have an RGB image, which I immediately take the red component. I then convert the resulting grayscale into bytes and display it in `Graph` using `draw_image`. However, only the background is shown and the red component image is not displayed. Let `img` be my RGB image. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

r,g,b = cv2.split(img)
data = bytes(Image.fromarray(r).tobytes())
width = len(b)
length = len(b[0])

layout = [[sg.Graph(
    canvas_size=(length, width),
    graph_bottom_left=(0, 0),
    graph_top_right=(length, width),
    key="-GRAPH-",
    change_submits=True, 
    background_color='black',
    drag_submits=True) ]]
window = sg.Window(layout, finalize=True)
window.Maximize()
graph = window["-GRAPH-"]
graph.draw_image(data = data, location=(0,width))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

[The result is nothing but black background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj59Y.png) I have checked that the image `img` and the red component `r` are both correct (i.e. statements like `imshow` will give the right image). The problem therefore lies in either the line `data = bytes(Image.fromarray(r).tobytes())` or `graph.draw_image(data = data, location=(0,width))`. However, both seem correct to me. What am I missing? Is there any workarounds? As a side note, I am not allowed to save any images.

Answer (score 0):

```py
Image.tobytes(encoder_name='raw', *args)
```

This method returns the raw image data from the internal storage. For compressed image data (e.g. PNG, JPEG) use save(), with a `BytesIO` parameter for in-memory data.

```py
import io
import cv2
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img = cv2.imread('D:/images.jpg')
r,g,b = cv2.split(img)
im = Image.fromarray(r)
width, height = im.size
buffer = io.BytesIO()
im.save(buffer, format='PNG')
data = buffer.getvalue()

layout = [[sg.Graph(
    canvas_size=(width, height),
    graph_bottom_left=(0, 0),
    graph_top_right=(width, height),
    key="-GRAPH-",
    change_submits=True,
    background_color='black',
    drag_submits=True) ]]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
# window.Maximize()
graph = window["-GRAPH-"]
graph.draw_image(data = data, location=(0, height))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there really no way to do this without saving...

Comment: It is the issue about the image format, not about saving or not, but saving work for it. Of course, you can convert your image into base64 format.

Comment: I guess I really do not know much about image format. My image is just a Numpy array in int32. My RGB image evaluated at a coordinate gives a tuple of three positive integers corresponding to their intensity (and gives one positive integer in case of grayscale). What kind of format should I convert this to such that it works in ```Graph```?

Comment: Numpy array just consist the raw data for each pixel, not in the file format, like PNG, PPM, GIF, so you need to do the conversion between raw data and file format of image. You can refer https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-photoimage/